# Debug Target is Missing (Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I keep getting the error "Debug Target is Missing" despite the path is set to "bin/debug" and the kbncmanagement.exe (Project's name) is present there. I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Hi, you need to provide more information. Whats is the project type? maybe look in the build output and copy and paste any errors?

Comment: It's a VB.net project.

Comment: Questions like these need to documented the installed anti-malware product.